# Объясните часть алгоритма для печати элементов матрицы (вектора в векторе) - C++

Tags: c++, матрицы, вектор

```
 std::for_each(imatrix.begin(), imatrix.end(), [](std::vector<int>& ivec)
{
    std::for_each(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), [](int i)
    {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(5) << i;
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
});
```

И вопрос по 1 же строчке: почему при описания вектора используется знак `&` (`std::vector<int>& ivec`)? Зачем он здесь? И что в этой же строчке означает символ `[]`?

В 3 строке 3-им аргументов функции `for_each` служит `[](int i)`, что это?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть вестор

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> imatrix;
```

то `imatrix[i]`, где `i` - некоторый индекс, это в свою очередь вектор, имеющий тип

```
std::vector<int>
```

То есть элементами вектора с типом `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` являются вектора `std::vector<int?`.

А элементами вектора с типом `std::vector<int>` являются скалярные величины с типом `int`.`, то есть целые числа.

Символ `&` означает ссылку на объект. Когда используется ссылка на существующий объект, то не создается копия объекта.

Итак, внешний алгоритм проходит по всем своим элементам типа `std::vector<int?`, а врутренний алгоирмт для каждого данного элемента проходит по всем его числам типа `int`

Что касается лямбда-выражения, то это функциональный объект, то есть это означает, что его можно "вызывать" как функцию, то есть этот объект предоставляет оператор-функцию, которую можно представить таким образом

```
void ( std::vector<int>& ivec )
{
    std::for_each(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), [](int i)
    {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(5) << i;
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

То есть это функция, которая в качестве аргумента получает "строку" "двумерного" вектора и аналогичным образом, внутри своего тела вызывая стандартный алгоритм `std::for_each` , которому также передается лямбда-выражение, которое распечатывает целочисленные элементы этой "строки".

Например, когда вы пишите лямбда-выражение

```
[](int i)
{
     std::cout << std::left << std::setw(5) << i;
}
```

как аргумент некоторого алгоритма или просто объявляете, то фактически компилятор создает некоторый объект, у которого есть оператор функция

Вы можете представить себе это следующим образом

```
struct Lambda
{
    void operator ()( int i ) const
    {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(5) << i;
    }
};
```

Теперь вы можете создать объект этого класса м вызвать его оператор функцию. Например

```
Lambda l;
l( 10 );
```

Попробуйте это сделать в своей программе, и вы получите представление, как работают лямбда-выражения.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    struct Lambda
    {
        void operator ()( int i ) const
        {
            std::cout << std::left << std::setw(5) << i;
        }
    };

    Lambda l;
    l( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Она выведет на консоль число 10.

Проще было бы сделать тоже самое без использования алгоритма `std::for_each`  и без лямбда-выражений, заменив вызовы алгоритма на цикл, основанный на диапазоне.

```
for ( std::vector<int> &row : imatrix )
{
    for ( int i : row )
    {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(5) << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Эти циклы делают то же самое, что и вызовы алгоритма `std::for_each`. Циклы на основе диапазонов, так называемые `range-based for loops` были введены в язык C++ с принятием нового стандарта языка в 2011 году.

Comment: Согласитесь, что идеоматические вложенные циклы по индексам выглядят лучше, а главное не вызывают лишних вопросов.

Comment: @avp Так как индексы не используются в данной задаче, то я предпочел бы циклы на основе диапазонов. В этом случае лямбда-выражения , которые затрудняют чтение кода, были бы исключены.

Comment: Вот я и думаю, что у ТС на самом деле затык с лямбдами (не  уверен, что он до конца понимает Ваш ответ).

Comment: @avp Всегда в комментариях можно обратиться за разъяснением.

Comment: Да, лямбда выражения я совсем не понял, если несложно, разъясните, пожалуйста

Comment: @МаксимПетров Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: @МаксимПетров, если разобрались, то можете еще и плюсануть (стрелка вверх) теперь  уже замечательный ответ.

Comment: 15 баллов нет(, как наберётся, обязательно лойсану!